# curl as a Zapier Webhook to Stripe

Tags: python, curl, stripe-payments, webhooks, zapier

I need to get some data from the balance transaction of Stripe, but Zapier doesn't have the ability to do that directly. I'd like to send a curl command in order to get this data. This is what Stripe provides in their docs:

```
$curl 
https://api.stripe.com/v1/balance/history/txn_1DFV3e2fooKYlo2CdUbarQBA \
-u sk_test_5z3BDUirhsfooIUypbari76o:
```

I'm thinking I can use a custom request for this, but have no idea how the formatting would work for the secret key

Comment: What data are you trying to get here exactly? One thing you could likely do is write  a small script, in the programming language of your choice, to grab this data from the Stripe API (https://stripe.com/docs/libraries), and then run it on a scheduled basis, or in response to webhooks created by Stripe in response to an action such as a Charge (https://stripe.com/docs/webhooks)

Comment: @duck - Zapier code steps don't allow for importing of libraries so I can't import the python library. That's why i'm hoping to use the curl method

Answer (score 3, accepted):

David here, from the Zapier Platform team.

The good news is this is very straightfoward. The setup is as such:

[image]

You want to `GET` a url (probably a mapped value instead of the hardcoded url you provided.

As for the auth, the `-u` param in `curl` is for user and takes the form `username:password`. In your case, it looks like an API key. So username is the key  and password is blank. Zapier lets you do the same thing, but using a bar (`|`) instead.

As a general rule of thumb, any configuration you can do in curl, you can also do in Zapier webhooks. You can also use Python or js and use the included requests libraries. More info [here](https://zapier.com/help/code/#utilities).

Comment: I'm getting this error "The app returned "Received unknown parameter: Note". This usually happens when your Zap is missing a required field or a field value isn't in a recognized format." which makes me think the GET webhook is adding unnecessary information. Is there a way to do this via a custom request instead?

Comment: The correct way to do this is to use the Custom Request webhook not the standard GET, as Zapier puts some unnecessary information into the request. Other than that, everything else @xavdid stated above works

Comment: Awesome! If this answer solved your problem, make sure to upvote it and mark it as correct ([info](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)).